# Perl push an element into an array that is inside of another array

Tags: arrays, perl

I have an array(lets call it X) and X contains arrays. I want to push an element(a string) into an array that is inside of X.
I've tried searching for quite a while and all i find are people trying to push arrays inside of other arrays.

I've tried the following code:

```
push(@X[0],$element);
```

Which gives me the error:

> Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at perlscript.pl line 30,
>   near "$element)"

I'm on perl 5 version 26.

Comment: If you want to push element to an array try this: ```push(@X,$element);```

Comment: @vinodk89: he want to push `$element` in the inner array-reference which is located at index 0 of `@X`

Comment: https://perlmonks.org?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Perl, arrays cannot contain other arrays. To make a multi-dimensional data structure, you  need references.

Consider this example.

```
use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @inner = qw(a b c);
my @outer = (
    \@inner,         # reference to existing array
    [100, 200, 300], # new anonymous array reference
);

print Dumper \@outer;
```

This prints

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c'
          ],
          [
            100,
            200,
            300
          ]
        ];
```

Your outer array is just that, an array. But the elements inside it are references to arrays. You can either reference an existing array, or create a new, anonymous one.

When dumping out the structure for debugging, note how `Dumper` from [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) requires a reference too, so we use the same notation with the `\`.

Now to add an element to `@inner` via its position inside `@outer`, you need to take the first element out `@outer`. To do that, the sigil changes, so you get `$outer[0]`. To pass that to `push`, we need to turn it into an array. That's called *dereferencing* as an array.

```
push @{ $outer[0] }, 'd';
```

When we `Dumper` it again, we get

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd'
          ],
          [
            100,
            200,
            300
          ]
        ];
```

Because the first element is a reference to a named array variable, we can also operate on it directly.

```
push @inner, 'e';
```

This will change the value of the first element in `@outer`, because both refer (see why it's called a *reference*?) to the same thing in memory.

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            'a',
            'b',
            'c',
            'd',
            'e'
          ],
          [
            100,
            200,
            300
          ]
        ];
```

We can't do that with the second element, because it started out as an anonymous reference.

---

Let's have a look at your warning.

> Experimental push on scalar is now forbidden at perlscript.pl line 30, near "$element)"

In Perl 5.20.0 `push` on references [was deprecated](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5200delta.html#push-on-reference-is-experimental) because it didn't work as intended, and started warning. In Perl 5.30.0 [this was changed](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldelta.html#Changes-to-Existing-Diagnostics) and it [is now a fatal error](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html#Type-of-arg-%25d-to-%25s-must-be-%25s-(not-%25s)), making your program die.

Also see [perlref](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [perlreftut](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html).

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for `push` is

```
push ARRAY, LIST
```

For example,

```
push @a, $element;
```

Whereever a variable name appear, you may replace the name with a block that evaluate to an reference.

```
push @{ $X[0] }, $element;
```

And that's what you need.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this does what you want:

```
push @{ $X[0] }, $element;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like everybody mentioned already, `push @{ $X[0] }, $element;`.

Since you say you are using v5.26, you can also use postfix dereferencing:

`push $X[0]->@*, $element;`